# Why does a character go up in the air when a character controller is added to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I add a `Character Controller` component to my character, my character goes up in the air by 0.08 units. This only happens when I start moving. The collider seems to be in the right position.

Here is a screenshot of the character with the `Character Controller` component:
[image]

Screenshot of my character settings:

[image]

My movement code:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform _orientation;

private CharacterController _controller;

private float xInput;
private float yInput;

private Vector3 _moveDirection;

private float rotationSpeed = 10f;
private float speed = 5f;

private void Awake()
{
    _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

private void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

private void Update()
{
    xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    yInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    _moveDirection = _orientation.forward * yInput + _orientation.right * xInput;

    RotatePlayerToCameraView();
    Move(_moveDirection);
}

private void RotatePlayerToCameraView()
{
    Vector3 viewDirection = transform.position - new Vector3(_orientation.position.x, transform.position.y, _orientation.position.z);
    _orientation.forward = viewDirection.normalized; // понять зачем это и как вообще

    gameObject.transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(gameObject.transform.forward, viewDirection.normalized, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
}

private void Move(Vector3 moveDirection)
{
    float scaledMoveSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    moveDirection = new Vector3(moveDirection.x, 0, moveDirection.z);

    _controller.Move(moveDirection * scaledMoveSpeed);
}
```

Comment: _my character goes up in the air by 0.08 units_ - The Character Controller defines the "skin width" at 0.08. Could that be the cause? I've never worked with unity, but that looks like a fairly solid correlation.

Comment: @MetroSmurf got it right. It has to do with physics processing as described in the official Unity documentation.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-skinWidth.html

Comment: I could add my comment as an answer if you think it will help others. Otherwise, I'd just delete the question.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Thank you so much! That helped! I can't believe I didn't see it. I think it might help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be correlation between the Character Controller's `skin width: 0.08` and the issue of *my character goes up in the air by `0.08 units`*.

Take a look at the [CharacterController.skinWidth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-skinWidth.html) Unity docs:

> Specifies a skin around the character within which contacts will be generated by the physics engine.

It appears the physics engine is using the width for the overall contacts.